# How to "normalize" spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, converters

I have a data array in the form of Excel spreadsheet. It looks like this (5 lines per 1 data array and it repeats every 5 lines):

[image: The pic showing how does is look now]

I need to convert the data into such a format:
[image: The pic showing how should it look like]

How can I convert the data to such a view. The main thing is to create an algorithm to organize the data and pull out the links from the cells where they are embedded like a hyperlink (but this is not so necessary)

The link to the original file is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/153w6211wou9iwv/soft.xlsx?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

To extract the URL from the link, you could create a UDF such as this:

```
    Function GetURL(rng As Range) As String
    On Error Resume Next
    GetURL = rng.Hyperlinks(1).Address 
    End Function
```

Then in your sheet, you could create formulas that you copy and paste every 5 rows.

```
C2 formula: =GetURL(A2)
D2 formula: =A2
E2 formula: =A3
F2 formula: =A4
```

[image]

After you have copied and pasted every 5 rows, then you can select your new columns, copy and paste as special values in another sheet, and then remove duplicates to get rid of your blank rows.